# Is AOF rebuild automatic when starting a redis server?

Tags: redis

If I configure a redis server to have persistence using append only files + specify automatic BGREWRITEAOF like this:

```
appendonly yes
appendfilename "appendonly.aof"
appendfsync everysec
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
```

does this mean that when launching a server instance it will pick up the aof file and remove duplicate commands at startup ? If not, is there a way to do to make sure that every time I launch a server instance I don't get duplicates from my aof file?

Answer (score 1):

Aof file will not rewrite when launching a redis server instance. With you configuration, rewrite would be triggered when `appendonly.aof` larger than 64mb and twice(100% up) than last rewrite.

The solution is, sending `BGREWRITEAOF` command manually after launching a redis server instance.

Comment: But does this guarantees that connected client won't see a replay of events? Isn't there an option to start the server wither a "rewrite" or at least, close it with a "clean" aof? I thought that "redis-server --bgrewriteaof" would work ...

Comment: since redis 2.4, `bgrewriteaof` was managed by redis cron task and mannually `BGREWRITEAOF` command. Redis do not support `--bgrewriteaof` param on starting. AOF file stores all commands records, no matter it clean or not, redis can restore all data from aof file. Connected clients won't see the restore procedure, they can see only the final key-value datas.

Comment: So, a clean aof file is not necessary, it is just more friendly for disk.

Comment: It is for me, I'm reacting to server updates, and this thing causes me 1000s of triggered callbacks on reconnection (I have keyspace events enabled). Anyway, not the answer I was looking for but I don't want the bounty to go to waste so ...

Comment: you can choose reacting after a bgrewriteof command when connected. Or, add rewriteaof code to redis source code with a param, then compile and use it.